# ios - pass a 4x4 matrix to glUniformMatrix4fv

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, shader

I'm trying to pass a 4x4 matrix to `glUniformMatrix4fv` but can't figure out the last bit. I create a 4x4 by directly inputing 16 values. `glUniformMatrix4fv` excepts an `UnsafePointer<GLfloat>!` as its last argument

```
var proj = GLKMatrix4(m: (
    -1.1269710063934326,
    0.0,
    -1.380141455272968e-16,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.800000011920929,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    -0.0,
    0.0,
    -4.950000286102295,
    -1.2246468525851679e-16,
    0.0,
    1.0,
    5.050000190734863)
)
var loc = GLint(_locations.uniforms.projection)
var f = GLboolean(GL_FALSE)
```

First try:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, f, proj.m)
```

raises

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<GLfloat>!'
```

second try:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, f, &proj.m)
```

raises

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)' to expected argument type 'GLfloat' (aka 'Float')
```

third try

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, f, &proj)
```

raises

```
Cannot convert value of type 'GLKMatrix4' (aka '_GLKMatrix4') to expected argument type 'GLfloat' (aka 'Float')
```

and finally

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, f, proj)
```

raises

```
Cannot convert value of type 'GLKMatrix4' (aka '_GLKMatrix4') to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<GLfloat>!'
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not good in swift, but are you sure that the matrix initialization is correct? You are trying to initialize an array (the m member) with a tuple. The m member itself should be what you have to pass to `glUniformMatrix4fv` as in your first try.

Comment: @BDL: The problem is that Swift maps C arrays to a Swift tuples. The initialization of GLKMatrix4 is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "problem" is that C arrays like the

```
float m[16];
```

in `struct _GLKMatrix4` are mapped to Swift as a *tuple:*

```
public var m: (Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)
```

but the `glUniformMatrix4fv()` function expects `UnsafePointer<GLfloat>`
(`float *` in C)  as the last argument.

In C, an array "decays" to a pointer to the first element when passed
to a function, but not in Swift. But Swift preserves the memory layout
of imported C structures, therefore you can pass a pointer to the tuple,
converted to a pointer to `GLfloat`:

```
// Swift 2:
withUnsafePointer(&proj.m) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, f, UnsafePointer($0))
}

// Swift 3/4:
let components = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: proj.m)/MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: proj.m.0)
withUnsafePointer(to: &proj.m) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: GLfloat.self, capacity: components) {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, f, $0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm getting started with Swift (with no background in Objective C) and I would not have figured that out myself!

Comment: @Fonix: I have added the corresponding Swift 3 code.

Comment: @MartinR awesome thanks, kind of counter intuitive that they made it even more verbose, thought Swift 3 was about getting things more concise :P guess it must have been a necessary evil

Comment: I get warning from complier that ```Swift Language Runtime: Simultaneous accesses to 0x1528c5100, but modification requires exclusive access```

Comment: @Abdoelrhman: Can you try it with `$0.withMemoryRebound(to: GLfloat.self, capacity: 16)` ?

Comment: that's applicable indeed, but why 16 or any other numbers?

Comment: @Abdoelrhman: It is the number of entries in a 4x4 matrix. Actually is was calculated wrong, the updated version should work for Swift 3 and 4.

Comment: @MartinR btw do you mind explaining this to me, I found it in code but I've almost zero knowledge about its functionality and openGL